# To what extent does Google limit page views in Google Books?

Tags: google-books

I suspect it varies between publishers, but is it known to what extent Google limits page views in Google Books? Rough estimates are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Publishers upload books via the Google Books Partner Program (http://books.google.com/googlebooks/tour/). A publisher sets the fraction of a book that can be previewed. This is [how the help page describes it](http://books.google.com/support/partner/bin/answer.py?answer=106170):

> You have control over the percentage
>   of pages that a user will be able to
>   view during a 30 day period. This
>   value can be set between 20% and 100%.
>   Partners can also choose to make their
>   book 100% browsable with the option to
>   download a PDF.